# What I can get the due left of every person easily for the following table [image attached]?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement this for two days now but stuck with logics! Please help.
What I can get the due left of every person easily for the following table [image attached] -
table link: https://ibb.co/xC53Cf4
where
1.`inc_due` is the column to get total due for specific person like `cust_id`
2. `inctype_id` =11 is the type of dues paid for specific person (`cust_id`)
3. echo only due left by `cust_id` or person id

I have tried to query casing error -

```
SELECT cust_id, (SUM(inc_due)) - sum(Case When inctype_id ==11)   
AS Total_due_left FROM incomes  GROUP BY cust_id;
```

Comment: Can you share your table's structure and what you want result look like, please?

Comment: @Zhiyong, here is the link to table structure
https://ibb.co/Jk50X20

and here is the error in sql query
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '==11)  
AS Total_due_left FROM incomes  GROUP BY cust_id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: I don't find inc_text column in your table defination. My suggestion is you could just give a example with create table sql, then sample data in this sql. Then give the expected result base on your example table.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what you really want....

I try my best to userstand what you want and the following are the sql, please have a look if this is what you want.

```
SELECT cust_id,
       SUM(
           case
               when inctype_id =11 then 0
               else inc_due
           end
       ) as Total_due_left
FROM incomes  GROUP BY cust_id;
```

The following are create sql I used:

```
create table incomes (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inctype_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cust_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `inc_amount` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `inc_due` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;


insert into `incomes` (inctype_id, cust_id, inc_amount, inc_due)
values
       (11, 1, 1, 1),
       (11, 2, 1, 1),
       (11, 3, 1, 1),
       (11, 4, 1, 1),
       (11, 5, 1, 1),
       (11, 6, 1, 1),
       (11, 1, 1, 1),
       (11, 2, 1, 1),
       (11, 3, 1, 1),
       (11, 4, 1, 1),
       (11, 5, 1, 1),
       (11, 6, 1, 1),
       (10, 3, 1, 1),
       (10, 4, 1, 1),
       (10, 5, 1, 1),
       (10, 6, 1, 1),
       (10, 3, 1, 1),
       (10, 4, 1, 1),
       (10, 5, 1, 1),
       (10, 6, 1, 1);
```

The result of running my query sql is as following:

```
mysql> SELECT cust_id,
    ->        SUM(
    ->            case
    ->                when inctype_id =11 then 0
    ->                else inc_due
    ->            end
    ->        ) as Total_due_left
    -> FROM incomes  GROUP BY cust_id;
+---------+----------------+
| cust_id | Total_due_left |
+---------+----------------+
|       1 |              0 |
|       2 |              0 |
|       3 |              2 |
|       4 |              2 |
|       5 |              2 |
|       6 |              2 |
+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Zhiyoung,
My head was freeze for long run..  Great! Thank you a lot!! My vote Up not accepted due to new account but I found the solution from your solution -
I got it as
__________


SELECT cust_id, 
SUM(inc_due) - (SUM(inc_amount)- SUM( case when inctype_id =11 then 0 else inc_amount end )) 
as Total_due_left FROM incomes GROUP BY cust_id;

Comment: glad to help! when you could, please accept my answer.

Comment: Sure, I would love to! I will be back when I get the point to Up Vote. Have a nice day.